# Amazon Redshift, SQL how would I compare the value of two timestamps to see if one is greater?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am currently using the function

`select date_cmp_timestamp('2008-01-25', '2008-01-24 06:43:24')`

But this one only compares a date and a timestamp.. Is there a function for comparing two timestamps so I can see if the seconds, hours, minutes are different? I haven't been able to find it, thank you

Comment: Can't you just compare the two values? `SELECT timestamp1 > timestamp2`

Comment: I was thinking It would be faster using a built in redshift function, but possibly not? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: I don't see why it would be any 'faster' using a function.

Comment: Because Amazon Redshift probably has a dedicated team who spent a lot of time writing the source code efficiently, for the functions to work on Redshift. Whereas > sign isn't native to redshift

Comment: Please let us know any results you obtain from your speed tests. It will be interesting to know!